# Процентная круговая диаграмма только с CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, диаграммы

Я нашел довольно красивую "круговую диаграмму процентов" и хочу создать ее только с помощью CSS.       Никакой анимации не требуется. Просто статичная «картинка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что если я хочу создать такую диаграмму, мне нужно использовать такие элементы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопросы**

1. Как создать элемент №2?
2. Как управлять формой элемента №2 для меньших (5%) или более высоких значений процента (80%)?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Percent pie chart with css only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52205399/7394871) от участника  [@Vic VKh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10064255/vic-vkh).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52205399/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать это с несколькими фонами.

от `0%` до `50%`

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#ccc, #ccc) content-box, 
    linear-gradient(var(--v), #f2f2f2 50%, transparent 0),
    linear-gradient(to right, #f2f2f2 50%, blue 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--v:-90deg"></div><!-- 0% -->
<div class="box" style="--v:-45deg"></div><!-- 12.5% -->
<div class="box" style="--v:  0deg"></div><!-- 25% -->
<div class="box" style="--v: 45deg"></div><!-- 37.5% -->
<div class="box" style="--v: 90deg"></div><!-- 50% -->

<p>The Формула [p = (18/5) * x - 90]. <small>Где x - это процент, а p - степень</small></p>
<p>for x = 5% --> p = -72deg </p>
<div class="box" style="--v:-72deg"></div>
```

от `50%` до `100%`

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:5px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#ccc,#ccc) content-box,
    linear-gradient(var(--v), blue 50%,transparent 0),
    linear-gradient(to right, #f2f2f2 50%,blue 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--v:-90deg"></div><!-- 50% -->
<div class="box" style="--v:-45deg"></div><!-- 62.5% -->
<div class="box" style="--v:  0deg"></div><!-- 75% -->
<div class="box" style="--v: 45deg"></div><!-- 87.5% -->
<div class="box" style="--v: 90deg"></div><!-- 100% -->

<p> Формула [p = (18/5) * x - 270]. <small>Где x - это процент, а p - степень</small></p>
<p>for x = 80% --> p = 18deg </p>
<div class="box" style="--v:18deg"></div>
```

Вы можете комбинировать и то, и другое вот так:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:5px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#ccc,#ccc) content-box,
    linear-gradient(var(--v), #f2f2f2 50%,transparent 0) 0/calc(var(--s)*100%)      ,
    linear-gradient(var(--v), blue    50%,transparent 0) 0/calc((1 - var(--s))*100%),
    linear-gradient(to right, #f2f2f2 50%,blue 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--v:-90deg;--s:1"></div>
<div class="box" style="--v:0deg;--s:1"></div>
<div class="box" style="--v:90deg;--s:1"></div>
<div class="box" style="--v:0deg;--s:0"></div>
<div class="box" style="--v:90deg;--s:0"></div>
```

Теперь мы можем оптимизировать, как показано ниже, чтобы учесть процентное значение:

```css
.box {
  
  --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#ccc,#ccc) content-box,
    linear-gradient(var(--v), #f2f2f2     50%,transparent 0) 0/min(100%,(50 - var(--p))*100%),
    linear-gradient(var(--v), transparent 50%,blue        0) 0/min(100%,(var(--p) - 50)*100%),
    linear-gradient(to right, #f2f2f2 50%,blue 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:5;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:20;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:50;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:60;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:75;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:100;"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связанный вопрос, чтобы получить другую версию: [Creating a static pie chart with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62924550/8620333)

---

Мы также можем рассмотреть маску для добавления прозрачности:

```css
body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,yellow);
}
.box {
  
  --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--v), #f2f2f2     50%,transparent 0) 0/min(100%,(50 - var(--p))*100%),
    linear-gradient(var(--v), transparent 50%,blue        0) 0/min(100%,(var(--p) - 50)*100%),
    linear-gradient(to right, #f2f2f2 50%,blue 0);
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
  mask-composite:exclude;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:5;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:20;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:50;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:60;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:75;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:100;"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также как ниже:

```css
.box {
  
  --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--v), transparent 50%,blue        0) 0/min(100%,(var(--p) - 50)*100%),
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%,blue 0);
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(var(--v), #f2f2f2     50%,transparent 0) 0/min(100%,(50 - var(--p))*100%),
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
  mask-composite:exclude;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:5;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:20;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:50;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:60;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:75;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:100;"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связанный вопрос: [Border Gradient with Border Radius](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51496204/8620333)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205730/7394871) от участника  [@иTemani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>